# Testing Firestore rules with unit testing v9 SDK and Firestore emulator

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js, firebase-security

I have a test suite that worked fine when I last used it. I didn't make any fundamental changes except for fixing some typos. Today it is failing with the following error:

```bash
  1) "before all" hook in "{root}"
  2) "after all" hook in "{root}"
  0 passing (308ms)
  2 failing

  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     Error: {"error":{"code":500,"status":"UNKNOWN"}}
      at loadFirestoreRules (file:///home/me/repositories/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/esm/index.esm.js:401:15)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async initializeTestEnvironment (file:///home/me/repositories/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/esm/index.esm.js:486:9)
      at async Context.<anonymous> (file:///home/me/repositories/my-app/firebase/firestore/__tests__/rules/users.notifications-inbox.test.mjs:26:13)

  2) "after all" hook in "{root}":
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cleanup')
      at Context.<anonymous> (file:///home/me/repositories/my-app/firebase/firestore/__tests__/rules/users.notifications-inbox.test.mjs:40:17)
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

What is `{root}` in a Mocha test suite? I have no such thing as a "root" file in my test suite. Just a couple of different `*.test.mjs` files that test different parts of the rule set.

Answer (score 1):

So the error was caused by a dot (`.`) in the `projectId` that I used in the `initializeTestEnvironment()` function. Apparently the emulator could not deal with it.

Replacing the dot with a dash (`-`) fixed the issue.

```js
const testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
  projectId: 'no-dot-in-this-string-allowed',
  firestore: { /* ... */ }
})
```

There might be other characters that are not allowed. If you find some, please leave a comment!

Comment: This also happened to me, but instead of a (.) it was (_) causing the issue.